# is it possible to use nested generic on function paramaters in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

As shown in the code below. i have a `compose` function that receive a generic function `fn` and the arguments of the function `fn`, `compose` want get the return type of `fn` and return it. but encounter the error: `Type 'F' is not generic.`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoQey.png)

#### Code And Playground

```js
function compose<F extends <T>(val: T) => any, A>(fn: F, val: A): ReturnType<F<A>> {
    return fn(val)
}

interface FooReturn<T> {
    foo: T
}
function foo<T>(val: T): FooReturn<T> {
    return {
        foo: val
    }
}

interface BarReturn<T> {
    bar: T
}
function bar<T>(val: T): BarReturn<T> {
    return {
        bar: val
    }
}

let fooRes = compose(foo, '') // expect FooReturn<string>
let barRes = compose(bar, 1) // expect BarReturn<number>
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBOBbADnAzgUwDwBiiOAHlDmACZaJ4AqAfABQBuAhgDYBcidAlIgC8DRGzABPADSIAgs2BgeBae26y+PAEo4oIAE5g649PgJ45IgN4BYAFCIHiPTv1IFrTnzsBfO3Zhg5HrAbBA4iARwcNq6BvRWdo6IwFE8dD52oJCwCMlR8R5q-EpRMa7xiDb2js6xSFVJSSlwPKqJjr62nf6BOMGh4QBCbHplcYyV7Q4ARiNpGbZZ0PBIs3oFqmkaiMOjLuMJ1Q61rpNHjWutnFOInd22HDp50Tg0gshomLhMzdIA5H8BAB6IHEEgmaARUr7MB4LBQPQBADmDDsjygiDW2jeHww2BwTDW0gAjMDQaQIRjdmNYWAQKhpn1UbYgA)

#### Expecting

Is it achievable?

Comment: No, you cannot directly instantiate generic function type parameters purely at the type level; [instantiation expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) require that you drop down to the value level (e.g., `typeof (someGenericFunc<A>)` instead of `SomeGenericFunc<A>`). Without higher kinded types as discussed in [ms/TS#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) there's no direct way to do this.  (more...)

Comment: (...continued) **But**, is there a reason you don't refactor to [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WGdMVw)?  You don't need to manually instantiate anything at the type level if you let TS's support for [higher order type inference from generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions).   Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Actually the generic function has been wrapped by a object. and i try [like this](https://tsplay.dev/wg85lN), but it not works.

Comment: Right, that's a missing feature or design limitation, see [ms/TS#49505](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49505). The support for higher order type inference from generic functions only works in very specific circumstances.  Overall TS lacks the ability to perform such generics-of-generics manipulation except for a few scenarios.  So now does this fully address the question and I should write up an answer? Or am I still missing something?

Comment: Yes, i appreciate your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript unfortunately lacks direct support for *instantiating* or *specifying* the type argument to a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function at the type level.  There is at least one open feature request for this; see [microsoft/TypeScript#44521](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44521), but so far it's not implemented.  Note that Typescript 4.7 introduced support for [*instantiation expressions*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions), which let you specify a type argument for a generic function *value* without calling it, but there is no analog for doing so purely at the type level.  Since `F` is just a function type and not a function value, then you cannot do anything like `F<A>`.

Note that the syntax `F<A>` would be ambiguous, since it's not clear if `A` should be a type argument to a generic *call signature* (what you're asking for here) or if it should be a type argument to a generic *type* (what it normally would be interpeted as).  Indeed since `F` is itself generic, neither of these work...  TypeScript also lacks  *higher kinded types* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213).  So `F<A>` is simply impossible in TypeScript as of TS5.1, no matter what.

---

As mentioned, TypeScript really doesn't have a lot of direct support for arbitrary manipulation of generic types or generic function types.  There are a few specific situations in which you can get some higher-order behavior, but they are essentially hardcoded heuristic features and not fully supported everywhere.  Instantiation expressions are once such feature.

There's also [higher order type inference from generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions).  This can actually be used to make your example code work:

```
function compose<A, R>(fn: (a: A) => R, val: A): R {
    return fn(val)
}

interface FooReturn<T> { foo: T }
function foo<T>(val: T): FooReturn<T> {
    return { foo: val }
}
let fooRes = compose(foo, '') 
// let fooRes: FooReturn<string>

interface BarReturn<T> { bar: T }
function bar<T>(val: T): BarReturn<T> {
    return { bar: val }
}    
let barRes = compose(bar, 1) 
// let barRes: BarReturn<number>
```

but it's fragile; you have to pass a generic function directly to `compose()`. You can't pass an object with a generic method, or any other more complicated nesting of the generic function.  This is considered a design limitation of TypeScript, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#49505](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49505).  So while some instances of this can be adequately handled, the general problem remains unsolved.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBOBbADnAzgUwDwCCANIgEoB8AFMGAFyKUCG9BAlIgLzlkkBujAGxat6pRAG8AsAChEcxACccUEAqQ1K-AaxkBfGTJhgoOBcEYQciAGJw4pZarB4AKtymz5wO-Rd6ZoJCwCIjecK5UWr4iNnYOKmoREjLyio5qyZ6pcmH0Winy+tJFhsam5paIAEKMCvFOSR6pAEa1vv7SgdDwSK0KEZqC0fQ1denObpmpSglITdlyfXmCBXJFJdICyqFxOFicyGiYuNR2JADk5+wyAPQ3iFtQO-Z79LYvs3hYUApGAObkGSPRB9Bz7DiHDDYHCUPokACM12kdwe21Br2qtXqiTAIFQzVM5CAA)